# A method applies the given function twice to the given argument

Tags: scala

For example, if given `Math.sqrt` and 2.0, it computes `Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(2.0))`.

Using the function:

```
def applyTwice[A](f: A => A, argument: A) = ???
```

Then testing the above example

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You are not asking a question. What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to apply a function twice to an argument and test it too.

For example, if you need to apply `Math.sqrt` twice to an argument, you can achieve it as shown in below code:

```
val sqrt: Double => Double = Math.sqrt
def applyTwice[A](f: A => A, d: A) = {
  f(f(d))
}

println(applyTwice[Double](sqrt, 625))

assert(applyTwice[Double](sqrt, 625) == 5.0) // will check if applyTwice return 5.0
```